# Is it possible to Add our own Ad banner?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad, banner-ads

I am planning to implement my own ad banner in my app instead of using other banners like iAd , AdMob.. etc.

1. Is there any possibility to add your own ad banners into apple App?
2. Does Apple provide any feature to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ad banner is nothing but a `UIView` within your main view.

What you must at least have is a mechanism to serve ads into that area, which `iAd`, `Admob` and other networks provide.

Comment: On UIView we can set Banner but how to show ads after clicking banner like apple providing iAd and how to make revenue by clicking ads?

Comment: It depends on what you program the UIView to do upon tapping. Like any other UIView, you can add events and selectors to the banner that will open up the ad upon tapping.